# How to pass function arguments to R model object

Tags: r

I would like to pass function arguments to R glm model objects. However, it seems my code below didnot work as R didn't recognize the passing argument.

I kept getting the error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
grid = (cbind(c('wl', 'livingd', 'deceasedt'), c('wl_time', 'ld_time', 'dec_time')))

for (k in 1:nrow(grid)){

  f=function(y=as.name(grid[k,1]), offset=as.name(grid[k,2])){
    m=glm(y~chain_class2+sex_new+age_cat+race_new, 
                      family=poisson(link='log'), 
                      data=poissonset, 
                      offset=log(offset/12))
  }
```

}

Is there a way to pass the variable names to the function? Thank you!

Comment: You are creating a new function with every iteration of the loop without calling it. What you should do instead, is create the function outside and only call it inside.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly. Actually the function will be passed to a boot() function to perform bootstrapping. However, my situation is even if the function is out of the loop, I cannot pass the arguments to glm object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grid = (cbind(c('wl', 'livingd', 'deceasedt'), c('wl_time', 'ld_time', 'dec_time')))

for (k in 1:nrow(grid)){

  f=function(y=as.name(grid[k,1]), offset=as.name(grid[k,2])){
    m=glm(get(y)~chain_class2+sex_new+age_cat+race_new, 
                      family=poisson(link='log'), 
                      data=poissonset, 
                      offset=log(get(offset)/12))
  }
}
```